# Save as in original folder

Tags: macos

How do you "save as" in the same folder as the original document.
When I open any file on my hard drive, and make some changes, but want to keep the original, when I try to "save as" a different name, the original folder where original document came from, is not the default, or even a choice on the "save as" screen

Comment: If one of the below answers has solved your issue, please mark it as the correct answer to move it out of the "Unanswered" section. If your issue hasn't been solved, please provide more information about what happened when you tried the below answers.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a small disclosure triangle next to where you input the document file name.

[image]

If you click on it, it will expand the Save As box and allow you to select a different folder to save the document to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about programs like: Numbers, Pages, Keynote... directly under the save button in the File menu there is a button for duplicate.