# Where is a "Save As" button in Excel on my MAC Pro to save as a New File Name?

Tags: ms-office, macos

Where is a Save As Button in Excel (or Word) on OS X  to save as a New File Name in a specific folder?

Comment: I do not use MS Office however in some cases the Save As... command is hidden on the File menu and can be shown by pressing the option key when clicking the File menu.

Comment: I posted an image on this other thread - it might help you in general as opposed to getting to the dialog via shortcuts... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161675/

Answer (score 1):

File menu > Save As... or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>S</kbd>

[image]

If you specifically want a button in the button bar, then View > Toolbars > Customise Toolbars & Menus > Commands, then Find it in the File section & drag to where you want it in the toolbar. [Note, Save as doesn't have an icon, so it will appear there in words.]

[image]

Comment: While ⌘⇧S probably works, nonetheless the menu show it as: ⇧⌘S

Comment: Apple's menu convention is to always put the ⌘ symbol last, because they use it to line up the fonts nicely in menus. Everywhere else, including stack exchange & even verbally, it's usually quoted as 'command shift letter' etc. Look, for instance at the File menu in Safari - how untidy would that be if they didn't line up to the ⌘ ?

Comment: Well looking at the menu in your answer, the comment "_Apple's menu convention is to always put the ⌘ symbol last,_" is certainly contradicted as the ⌘ symbol is not last at all and is first in most and the middle in a few.  Anyway I'll always post it as it shows on the menu to avoid confusion when showing a picture of the menu.

Comment: Where in this menu is it ***not*** last? [before the letter, of course, anything else would be totally ridiculous - it's the typographical equivalent of lining up numbers to the decimal point] http://i.stack.imgur.com/zjyE4.png & please try to follow a convention that has been around 30 years or more, rather than your own idea of what it ought to be.

Comment: As I said "While ⌘⇧S probably works, nonetheless the menu show it as: ⇧⌘S" and the very fact that Apple puts "⇧⌘S" on the menu, **not** "⌘⇧S" I am not following an idea of my own but what is absolutely visible right in front of me! So if it's not "⇧⌘S" then Apple is wrong for putting it as "⇧⌘S" on the menu!

Comment: & I refuse to be drawn any further on this dozy logic.